# why is html select element is undefined?

Tags: javascript, html

This is really strange.  I have other select boxes defined in the same way which work fine, but this one supposedly is undefined.
Here is the html:

```
<select id="selWatchlist" style="float:left">
    <option value=0>My First Watchlist</option>
</select>
```

I can see one option in the dropdown list at this point.

Here is the javascript that appends another option:

```
$('#selWatchlist').append('<option value="' + item.id + '">' + item.name + '</option>');
console.log("loadWatchlists: selWatchlist.options.length=", $('#selWatchlist').options.length);
```

The value that was just appended to the select element correctly shows up in the list.  I can see two items in the dropdown, "My First Watchlist" and "My Portfolio" (which is coming from a backend call).

But the console.log says `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"`

How can `$('#selWatchlist')` be undefined when the append to it worked fine and I can see two options?  I've spent hours trying to track down the problem to no avail.

Comment: The undefined thing is not `$('#selWatchlist')` as you say but `$('#selWatchlist').options`. Inspect the value of `$('#selWatchlist')` and see that it's not the DOM element you're thinking it is.

Comment: How do I inspect it's value?  I've searched the entire code for "selWatchlist" and its the only one in the html.  I don't understand why a [0] is needed, as others suggest, when there is only 1.

Comment: No, `$('#selWatchlist')` is not "the" element, it's a function call to jQuery, which gives you a "proxy" (a "jQuery object") to the dom element so that you can do some cool stuff on it (like `$('#selWatchlist').slideToggle()`) that is not available in vanilia JS. This jQuery object keeps the actual DOM element(s) inside it, and you can access it (them) by array indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
console.log("loadWatchlists: selWatchlist.options.length=", $('#selWatchlist')[0].options.length);
```

adding `[0]` or `get(0)` onto the end of any jQuery object gives you the "true" DOM element (or the first DOM element, if several were matched).

Comment: Yes, that worked!  I've searched the entire code for "selWatchlist" and its the only one in the html. I don't understand why a [0] is needed when there is only 1.  I'm not sure if you were the first or ceejayoz was first but thank you both for answering!

Comment: @user3217883 Because `$('#selWatchlist')` returns all the matching elements. So 
Even if the matching list is one, U need to get an element's ID.   So u can upvote both answers  :) Glad to help u

Comment: I upvoted them both but I don't understand your comment.  As I understand, an id is unique, unlike a class which can be shared among elements.  So if its unique, how can there be more than one matching element?

Comment: @user3217883 The `$` function has to work with many different selectors. In order to have a consistent return type, it returns an array of items even if there can only be one match. (You'll also find sometimes that while you're not *supposed* to have multiple elements with an ID, some folks accidentally do it.)

Answer (score 1):

`$('#selWatchlist')` returns a list of matching elements, not just one element, so it doesn't have `.options`. You need to get the first element out of that list:

```
$('#selWatchlist').get(0).options.length
```